# Can I keep an element the width of the longest element?

Tags: html, css

I have a `button` element with four `span` elements.

```html
<button>
    <span style="display: none;">Text 1</span>
    <span style="display: none;">Text 2</span>
    <span>Text 3</span>
    <span style="display: none;">Text 4</span>
</button>
```

I want to keep the width of `button` element the same, while changing the active texts (Width of button = Width of longest text). I tried making the `span` elements `position: absolute` and `left: 0; top: 0;` and the `button` element `position: relative` and using `opacity: 0` to change the active texts, but the `span` elements don't affect the `button` element when `position: absolute` is set. Is this possible using pure css or will I need javascript for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use CSS grid and make all the spans on the same track then consider opacity (or visibility) to hide the text:

```css
button {
  display:grid;
}
button * {
  grid-area:1/1;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <span style="opacity:0;">long Text 1</span>
    <span style="opacity:0;"> very long Text 2</span>
    <span>Text 3</span>
    <span style="opacity:0;">Text 4</span>
</button>
```